# Hibernate : refresh on detached object - weird behavior

Tags: java, hibernate

I have been using Hibernate for a project and I have some questions left on how it really works. In particularly with refresh on persistent/detached state and the difference between createQuery, get and load from the session.

In the following examples, "groupe" is initially in a persistent state with modified value that are not yet commited

Case #1

```
// createQuery before evict
// g and groupe point to the same object
Groupe g = (Groupe) session.createQuery("from Groupe as g where g.idGroupe = '" + theid + "'").uniqueResult();
System.out.println("groupe=" + groupe.getTitle()); // modified value
System.out.println("g=" + g.getTitle()); // modified value

session.evict(groupe);
System.out.println("groupe=" + groupe.getTitle()); // modified value
System.out.println("g=" + g.getTitle()); // modified value

session.refresh(groupe);
System.out.println("groupe=" + groupe.getTitle()); // modified value
System.out.println("g=" + g.getTitle()); // modified value
```

Case #2

```
// get before evict
// g and groupe point to the same object
Groupe g = (Groupe) session.get(Groupe.class, theid);
System.out.println("groupe=" + groupe.getTitle()); // modified value
System.out.println("g=" + g.getTitle()); // modified value

session.evict(groupe);
System.out.println("groupe=" + groupe.getTitle()); // modified value
System.out.println("g=" + g.getTitle()); // modified value

session.refresh(groupe);
System.out.println("groupe=" + groupe.getTitle()); // value from database
System.out.println("g=" + g.getTitle()); // value from database
```

Case #3

```
// load before evict
// g and groupe point to the same object
Groupe g = (Groupe) session.get(Groupe.class, theid);
System.out.println("groupe=" + groupe.getTitle()); // modified value
System.out.println("g=" + g.getTitle()); // modified value

session.evict(groupe);
System.out.println("groupe=" + groupe.getTitle()); // modified value
System.out.println("g=" + g.getTitle()); // modified value

session.refresh(groupe);
System.out.println("groupe=" + groupe.getTitle()); // value from database

System.out.println("g=" + g.getTitle()); // value from database
```

Why is there a different behavior after the refresh action with createQuery ?
Is this a normal behavior ? If yes, can someone explain the difference ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple:

- Using query causes session to flush the modifications. When you `evict` your entitiy, the changes are already persisted.
- On the other hand getting entity by its identifier does not force session to be flushed.

All three cases are showing **value from database** after the `refresh`. Only in the first case it happens that the *value from database* is the **modified value**.

---

If you want the reasoning behind this behavior:

- Hibernate can not be sure whether a dirty entity is not relevant for the query. For example for modified `foo` property and query `SELECT entity FROM Entity entity WHERE entity.foo = 'BAR'` you might get incorrect results if the changes are not flushed before query execution.
- When you are getting entity by its identifier, Hibernate is able to do a simple lookup inside the session and get the correct entity. There is no need to flush any non-persisted changes.

Hope its clear.

Comment: Thank you, it makes more sense now :)